# GET Request from PHP using file_get_contents with parameters

Tags: php, http, get, file-get-contents

I want to send a GET request to an external site, but also want to send some parameters

for example i've to send a get request to example.com

i want to execute www.example.com/send.php?uid=1&pwd=2&msg=3&phone=3&provider=xyz

My code is :

```
$getdata = http_build_query(
array(
    'uid' => '1',
    'pwd' => '2',
 'msg'=>'3',
 'phone'=>'9999',
 'provider'=>'xyz'
 )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
 array(
    'method'  => 'GET',
    'content' => $getdata
)
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/send.php', false, $context);
```

I get a server error .

Comment: What does the server error say?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `content` option is used with `POST` and `PUT` requests. For `GET` you can just append it as a query string:

```
file_get_contents('http://example.com/send.php?'.$getdata, false, $context);
```

Furthermore, the `method` defaults to `GET` so you don't even need to set options, nor create a stream context. So, for this particular situation, you could simply call `file_get_contents` with the first parameter if you wish.

Comment: thanks for the reply : The previous code was sending some data to the server, but the request wasn't being processed properly.
However, with the code that you suggested and error appears " HTTP Error 1.1"

Comment: Isnt cURL way better in handling these kind of requests and such?

Comment: @redskin Could you help me out  with cURL ? Thanks

Comment: sure man.. add me on skype @ redskins80. If im online, dont hesitate to send a buzz!

Comment: @Anant wich 1.1 error? 500? that probably has something to do with the receiving part of the script. check your php log

Comment: @LordNeo This was around 6 years back :) Thanks for the help though!