# Passing file url with variables into Postmark causing file not found issue

Tags: php

So I'm using Postmark to send emails and the class I have requires a variable as the message body, as below:

```
$email->to(Input::post('email'))->subject("Verify Your Email Address")->html_message($html)->send();
```

This works fine if I set `$html` as just plain `html`.

What I am trying to do is send the contents of another php file from my site as this html.

I have tried:

```
$Vdata = file_get_contents('verification.php');
```

this works fine but as soon as I try and pass variables in it gives me an error:

> file not found error

And sends a blank email, for example:

```
$Vdata = file_get_contents('verification.php?url=blah');
```

Essentially I just need `$html` to be the contents of `verification.php?url=blah` so that I can pass in variables to that file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7352884/3599237

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a local file inclusion, which means filenames ONLY. URLs are not permitted (query strings in particular) because you're **NOT** doing an HTTP request. PHP is going to look for a file whose name literally contains `?`, `u`, `r`, etc... which of course doesn't exist.

If you want to use query strings, then you have to use a full-blown absolute URL, including the protocol:

```
include('http://....?url=...');
```

However, this is incredibly inefficient, and also highly dangerous. Since you're now EXECUTING the file specified in the url. you're going to get its output, not the raw PHP code in the file.

If you want to pass data to an included file, then just variables:

```
$foo = 'bar';
include('test.php');
```

and use look for/use those variables in the file.

Comment: Another way of executing an external file is `ob_start();
include('verification.php');
$Vdata = ob_get_clean();`