# PHP file_get_contents with var params fails

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a website that receives some parameters and a phone number is returned.

**This is the call i do from other page:**

```
$phoneNumber= file_get_contents("https://page.company.test/?app=$appid&affiliateid=$affiliatep&laNG=en&country=$countryp&sav=$savactive");
```

It **fails** passing the url like this. I echoed the whole url and the vars are set correctly.

**But if i use the url like this, it works:**

```
file_get_contents("https://page.company.test/?app=tsc&affiliateid=main&laNG=en&country=au&sav=false");
```

What do I miss?

Comment: have you try without https (with http)? (file_get_contents("http://tfnlicense.safebytes.com/?app=tsc&affiliateid=main&laNG=en&country=au&sav=false");)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not pass variables but use string now.

Try expand the variables and concatenate to string

```
$phoneNumber= file_get_contents("https://page.company.test/?app=".$appid."&affiliateid=".$affiliatep."&laNG=en&country=".$countryp."&sav=".$savactive)
```

See more convinient way with all options in array: [GET Request from PHP using file_get_contents with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7352832)

Comment: Not working for me either :( ,           $phoneNumber= file_get_contents("https://page.company.test/?app=".$appid."&affiliateid=".$affiliatep."&laNG=en&country=".$countryp."&sav=".$savactive);

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks for the help, on the other side the dev made it mandatory to use the affiliateid parameter, he just pinged me to use "main". Also used this one and works great                                   $phoneNumber= file_get_contents("https://page.company.test/?app=".$appid."&affiliateid=main".$affiliatep."&laNG=en&country=".$countryp."&sav=".$savactive);

Answer (score -1):

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) urlencode — URL-encodes string
>
> string urlencode ( string $str )
>
> This function is convenient when
> encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient
> way to pass variables to the next page.

Try to encode your url to pass into the `file_get_contents()` function.

```
$url = "https://page.company.test/?app=$appid&affiliateid=$affiliatep&laNG=en&country=$countryp&sav=$savactive";
$url = urlencode($url);
$phoneNumber = file_get_contents($url);
```

See the php documentation for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Tried this one Fin
$url = "https://page.company.test/?app=$appid&affiliateid=$affiliatep&laNG=en&country=$countryp&sav=$savactive";
$url = urlencode($url);
$phoneNumber= file_get_contents($url);
But i get nothing, while i echo the $url i see this:   https%3A%2F%2Ftfnlicense.safebytes.com%2F%3Fapp%3Dtsc%26affiliateid%3D%26laNG%3Den%26country%3Dus%26sav%3Dfalse

Comment: The link you provided does not give any result in my browser as well. So what should the link be then?