# RESTful API PHP Content Type

Tags: php, api, rest, content-type

I am writing a RESTful API in the CakePHP framework. Using the POSTMAN app I am testing a delete method with the headers set as follows:

```
Content-Type application/json
```

I am sending my data in the body as RAW:

```
{"id":"8"}
```

MY API is routing the request as I would expect to my controller, and I'm reading the body with:

```
json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),'true');
```

This gives me empty data with the above parameters. However if I change the method type to POST or I remove the content type form the headers then I get content in the body.

Any ideas, seems like strange behaviour!

Comment: This looks to answer you question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352832/get-request-from-php-using-file-get-contents-with-parameters

Comment: If that is being sent using `AJAX` and deleting out the Database via the ID, careful that the ID is stripped for Injections and they can inspect the element and delete any ID so watch who can and can't delete.

Comment: A DELETE method typically shouldn't include a body.