# insert content of a file while changing values inside

Tags: php

```
$title = '';

function insert($file){
    global $title;    
    $title = 'lorem';
    $cnt = file_get_contents(`abc.php`);
    echo $cnt;

    $title = ' ipsum';
    $cnt = file_get_contents(`abc.php`);
    echo $cnt;
}
```

**abc.php**

```
<div class='title'><?php echo $title; ?></div>
```

So I need to insert `abc.php` while changing variables inside.

In the above (simplified) example I'm expecting `lorem ipsum` as the result, but I'm getting empty div `.title`

Comment: this will never work, because [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will get file content as a string, it will never evaluate the php code inside it, you should use [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) if you want to have a template string with replaceable placeholders.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman, any example of using `sprintf` in the above scenario, pls

Comment: I added an answer, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your current flow it not working.

Try with `str_replace` in the current file and in `abc.php` file declare one keyword like `#TITLE#`

```
$title = '';

function insert($file){
    global $title;    
    $title = 'lorem';
    $cnt = file_get_contents(`abc.php`);
    $cnt = str_replace("#TITLE#",$title,$cnt);
    echo $cnt;

    $title = ' ipsum';
    $cnt = file_get_contents(`abc.php`);
    $cnt = str_replace("#TITLE#",$title,$cnt);
    echo $cnt;
}
```

**abc.php**

```
<div class='title'>#TITLE#</div>
```

Hope this work for you.

Comment: as a concept - your solution is ok, but I'm afraid it wil be time consuming in case `abc.php` is a large file. Have you any idea why `varables-version` doesn't work. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: You should pass variable in ```GET``` as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7352884/4781696 ref link but I am not suggesting to use this but if this full fill your requirement then use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$template = "<div class='title'>%s</div>";

echo sprintf($template, 'this is title1');
echo sprintf($template, 'this is title2');
```

Or more readable HTML template, using [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

PHP code:

```
$body = file_get_contents('template.html');
$patterns = array(
  '/{title}/'
);
$replacements = array(
  'this is title',
);
$body = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $body);
```

template.html:

```
<div class='title'>{title}</div>
```